# MTLBlitCommandEncoder in AVCaptureSession does not show image properly. Do I have to use display shader function?

Tags: ios, swift, metal, avcapturesession, metalkit

When drawing images to `MKTView`, `MTLBlitCommandEncoder` sounds a good idea as we can simply copy texture to `currentDrawable` of `MKTView`. Code is much shorter than `MTLComputeCommandEncoder/MTLRenderCommandEncoder` which ask for `pipelineState` and `descriptor`.

However my code below does not show image properly, for (I guess) different sizes of input texture and output one. Any tips or suggestions for using `MTLBlitCommandEncoder` in such case? Or do I have to use shader function as we see in below post/git?

[Display JPEG image using MTKView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605241/display-jpeg-image-using-mtkview)

https://github.com/navoshta/MetalRenderCamera

```
func draw(in view: MTKView) {
  guard let drawable = view.currentDrawable else {return}
  guard let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() else {fatalError()}
  guard let blitEncoder = commandBuffer.makeBlitCommandEncoder() else{fatalError()}
  guard let texture = self.texture else {fatalError()}
  let targetW = min(texture.width, drawable.texture.width)
  //720, 1125 in my case
  let targetH = min(texture.height, drawable.texture.height)
  //1280, 2436

  blitEncoder.copy(from: texture, sourceSlice: 0, sourceLevel: 0, sourceOrigin: MTLOrigin(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0), sourceSize: MTLSizeMake(targetW, targetH, texture.depth), to: drawable.texture, destinationSlice: 0, destinationLevel: 0, destinationOrigin: MTLOrigin(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0))
  blitEncoder.endEncoding()
  commandBuffer.present(drawable)
  commandBuffer.commit()
  commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()
}
```

Thank much in advance for your helps.

Comment: Do the two textures have the same pixel format? Same sample count? Are they compressed? Have you tried running with Metal Validation enabled? Does it trigger an assert?

Comment: Hi Ken, thank you for your comment. FPS is same at 30. Metal Validation shows not warnings. Pixel format is bgra8Unorm at mtkView.colorPixelFormat and CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage. But device active format is kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange. Is this the issue?

Comment: MTLPixelFormat has no 8bitYpCbCr, while iPhone X device available formats are only 420YpCbCr.

Comment: The important thing is that `texture.pixelFormat` and `drawable.texture.pixelFormat` match. Otherwise, the `copy(...)` method will fail. Given that the Core Video pixel format is YpCbCr, it seems likely that the texture doesn't really contain RGB (or BGR) data and `bgra8Unorm` is just used because there's nothing better. Also, since it's planar, there are probably multiple textures or maybe slices. You can try examining the texture in Xcode's GPU frame debugger. You'll probably need to convert the data one way or another. A shader seems a sensible approach.

Comment: Thanks much, Ken. Seems I have to covert/extract data, then shader + renderCommandEncoder would be straightforward.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use YpCbCr from the camera? If not, it's easier to tell the camera to give you BGRA data instead.

Comment: Hi Matthijs. Yep, you're right. I set kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA in my video output setting. But that didn't solve size issue. So I ended up using MPSImageLanczosScale to adjust input texture to drawable.texture. I guess this is the best/simple solution when you put capturesession samplebuffers to mtkview.

Comment: A blit is just a copy, it would only work with the same pixel format and the same width and height in the src and dst. If you want to resize then a scaling shader invocation is required. You should also make sure your BGRA pixel data is getting represented as sRGB pixels so that the scaling is able to correctly interpret the pixel values coming from the camera as sRGB with gamma encoding as opposed to straight linear values. You can find working source code for this using Metal at this github project: https://github.com/mdejong/MetalBT709Decoder